# how to automatically create folders in document library

Tags: 2013, workflow, document-library, folder

I'm new to SharePoint and coming from a Drupal background.

I have a document library where I want to automatically create a folder every 24 hours with a name prefix i.e... `'folder1', 'folder2'` and so on.

can someone help me to do this using SharePoint 2013 workflow.

Comment: You'll learn with SharePoint, try to avoid using folders.  Use metadata instead to group/categorize items.

Comment: @wjervis thanks for your response but in this case we need folders so a MoveIT/autoSys job can drop files in those folders on daily basis.

Comment: I see.  Also, have you considered using a timer job instead?  Since you want this to run on a schedule, a timer job might be better suited for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For workflow being able to create folders, you need to **assign the folder content type** to the list and then create new item from workflow using **folder content type**.

**Add folder content type in list**

- Open the list in an internet browser. There will be an option bar at the top.
- Select “List” and choose “List Settings” in the new ribbon.
- Click on “Advanced Settings”, activate the option “Enable management of content types” and click on “OK”.
- Back to the list settings.
- Click on “Add from existing content types”.
- In the new page, select “Folder Content Type” from the dropdown menu.
- Add the content type named “Folder” to the list content types by selecting it and clicking on the arrow pointing to the right.
- Click on “OK” to save the new assignment.

**Create folder using workflow**

- To create a folder, choose the action “Create a list item”.
- Click on action to fill more information.
- Choose the list where the folder shall be added from the dropdown field.
- If your list has multiple content types, a field to assign a value to, will automatically be added. It is called “Content Type ID”. If it is not present, click on “Add” to add this field.
- Select “folder” from dropdown.
- Set title field for folder name.

**Make WF run daily**

- Document Library Settings
- Open Information management policy settings
- Select "Folder"
- Enable Retention
- Add a Retention steg
- set + 1 days (To make workflow run daily)
- Select "Start a workflow"

Comment: Thanks @Melad Francis for your quick response. I need to do this in document library not lists. Can I follow the same process with document libraries?

Comment: this is for Document Library

Comment: what options do you get

Comment: I've done till the last step, how do I start the workflow ?

Comment: I found 'Start workflow'..... Now how do I create a folder with something like folder1, Folder2 so every time workflow runs it adds a number 1, 2 , 3 after the word 'Folder'

Comment: your created folders automatically will count up