# Automate moving or copying folder(Not contents) that is created in SharePoint and creating or moving it to a Network Share drive

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a workflow that takes the Title and Name form a SharePoint list form and automatically creates a folder in a SharePoint Library. My desire is to Copy or Move that folder to a Network Share Drive.

The users can then copy folders to the newly created folder out on the network share.

I do not need contents as the folder is empty. So what is the best way to automate the move of a folder from a SharePoint Library anytime a new folder is created in that Library.

NOTE: I do not want to synch Files from SharePoint to file explorer. I want a folder created in file explorer for end users to copy files to from someplace else.

```
    SPFile.MoveTo
```

Or should I use a

```
    spfile moveto
```

I am not a developer and don't code I just need a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to another post here for a sample using SPFile.MoveTo or SPFile.CopyTo method:
[SharePoint SPFile : MoveTo and CopyTo method.](https://teamspointdotcom.wordpress.com/2017/01/07/sharepoint-spfile-moveto-and-copyto-method/)

The ideal way to automate this process in SharePoint on-premises would still be using a workflow. You can add a **Create List Item** action in the workflow you are currently using, and select **Folder** for the field `Content Type Id`.

See an example here: [how to automatically create folders in document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/215817/how-to-automatically-create-folders-in-document-library)